# Blender: copy and paste flipped pose not working

Tags: blender

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to make a simple character walk cycle but in action editor I can't flip keyframes properly

> "inverted keyframes didn't get pasted properly".

Red pointed area in given image shows only 2 bones inverted motion but I need all of them to invert. I tried `Ctrl+c` and `Ctrl+shift+v` but still can't get it working.

Want to add flipped keyframes in red area:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Select ALL of the key frames for all of the bones you want. Hit shift D to move them over. Then place your timeline in the middle of they key frames and hit <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>-1</kbd>. That should flip your pose.